# MySQL - number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can't figure out why this code isn't working:

```
$update_SQL = $db->prepare($SQL_update);
$update_SQL->execute([$SQL_values]);
```

And these are dumps of the two strings being inserted into those statements:

```
$SQL_update = UPDATE laptops SET asset_tag = :asset_tag WHERE id = :id
$SQL_values = 'asset_tag' => 5544, 'id' => 23
```

Comment: `$update_SQL->execute([':asset_tag' => 5544, ':id' => 23]);`  and check .`:` is missed

Comment: perhaps an old version of php that doesn't support []. so try : $update_SQL->execute(array('asset_tag' => 5544, 'id' => 23));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `:` in your code:-

```
$update_SQL = $db->prepare($SQL_update);
$update_SQL->execute([':asset_tag' => 5544, ':id' => 23]);
```

So actually what you have to do is:-

```
$SQL_values =[':asset_tag' => 5544, ':id' => 23]; // create array like this
$update_SQL = $db->prepare($SQL_update);
$update_SQL->execute($SQL_values); // pass that array
```

Or

```
$SQL_values =['asset_tag' => 5544, 'id' => 23]; // create array like this
$update_SQL = $db->prepare($SQL_update);
$update_SQL->execute($SQL_values); // pass that array
```

Note:- `execute` won't accept a string, it must be an array.

Comment: Ahhh! 'execute' won't accept a string, it must be an array. Got it!

Comment: @Anant: ":" are not a necessity. I work every time without it and it works fine. take a look about comment of "VolGas" in documentation link:http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.execute.php#71929

Comment: @IlyasMimouni  i got your point, but what i want to show to OP is that he have to use array not the string. I have updated that too what you said